# Constructing an explicit map for the double cover of the Klein Bottle by a Torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I know it's been asked before, but I wanted to know if my answer is correct (as I haven't been able to verify it).

I visualize $P^2$ # $P^2$ as an upper hemisphere (with its boundary equator appropriately identified) connected through a small tube with a lower hemisphere (also with its boundary equator identified); basically, I visualized it explicitly as sort of a sandglass.

Now define $q$: $S^1\times S^1\mapsto $ $P^2\#P^2$ as follows:

Before defining the map partition, the upper half of the circle as follows: begins with a point at $(1,0)$, then let $U_1$ be an open arc in the first quadrant $($the one with $x,y > 0)$ starting at $(1,0)$ but not including it; then let $U_2$ be a closed arc that starts at the first quadrant (it starts and includes the point where $U_1$ ends) and continues to the second quadrant. And then let $U_3$ be an open arc, which starts where $U_2$ ends and ends at the point $(-1,0)$ (since it's an open arc, it doesn't contain the endpoints).

Now for the map:

$(1,0) \times S^1$ is sent to the boundary of the lower hemisphere (since the boundary has antipodal points identified, this will doubly cover it).

$U_1 \times S^1$ is sent to the lower hemisphere (minus the part that occupies the tube, of course).

$U_2 \times S^1$ is sent to the tube

$U_3 \times S^1$ is sent to the upper hemisphere.

$(-1,0) \times S^1$ is sent to the boundary of the upper hemisphere

Then repeating the same process to the low part of the circle covers the upper/low hemispheres and the tube again without covering the boundaries again.

Is this a correct map for the double cover of the Klein Bottle? This covers the Klein Bottle twice. Continuity follows via the gluing lemma. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two-fold covering from Torus $\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^1$ to Klein-bottle$=\frac{[0,1]\times [0,1]}{(x,0)\sim(x,1)\text{ and }(0,y)\sim (1,1-y)}$ given by $$\big(e^{2\pi ix},e^{2\pi iy}\big)\longmapsto\begin{cases} [2x,y]_K&\text{ if }0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2},\\ [2x-1,1-y]_K &\text{ if }\frac{1}{2}\leq  x\leq 1.\end{cases}$$[image]

Comment: Thanks, I see that going via the polygonal presentation approach is far simpler. Although my intent in making the thread was for someone to check my solution (as I don't have access to classes or a solutions manual), but thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that, I have not read your solution correctly. Just as the information I posted. I can not add a picture in the comment box. Maybe someone else will answer your question.